# Can the information ( i ) icon be used to define a field name?

Tags: icons

What's the best UX when it comes to using the 'i' (information) icon when defining a field name?

Currently I have the field name defined above the field; before and after the the input field itself, I have a static name describing the input. For example, I want to replace the field name that says `Pixels` with an info icon than, on hover, shows the field name.

[image: Form with field label (Actual/Effective), field name (Pixels) above input field and field units (Megapixel)]

[image: Form with field label (Actual/Effective), icon above input field and field units (Megapixel)]

Answer (score 2):

The "i" seems a little out of place replacing the "pixels".

Part of the problem seems to be that you have both "Pixels" and "Megapixel" as units for the number field, and I'm not sure that the "Pixels" is actually needed.

I assume that the value is the number of megapixels the user wants, so losing the word "Pixels" is a good thing.

The "i" (represented as "?") could then be placed on the same line:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNyvNV.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>